# tried running this code expecting even numbers nut i got odd numbers, explanation pls

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: i mean, its suppose to display odd numbers but displays even numbers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: from the code i was expecting to get the odd numbers displayed but i was getting the even number as output and i want know why its like that instead of the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

An even number, such as 2, 4, 6, 8, ... is divisible with 2, so

```
i % 2 != 0
```

is true if and only if `i` is odd. So, whenever you have an odd value, the loop continues and does not print and whenever you have even numbers, the criteria is false and the value is printed.